# How do I use Two ajax calls at the same time to process records and update the HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am developing an application to process the daily credit card sales of a store. All the data necessary to process the transactions through the merchant is stored in a mySQL database. When the user clicks on "Process Transactions" a page loads displaying each transaction row by row in a HTML table. Using onLoad() I am using ajax to call a .php page which in turn queries the database for all the transactions, and then in a loop processes the transactions through the merchant and updates the database with either a success or fail. This part is working perfectly.

My question is this: I would like to update the HTML table as the processing is taking place and turn the HTML table rows red for fail and green for success. Trying to do this in a For Loop (updating each row after each transaction processes) does not work. I know I can use AJAX setInterval() to call another .php page every 2 seconds which queries the database for completed records and updates the HTML table with the results returned. My .php pages are written and working. I have the AJAX set up and working for the first part (processing the transactions). What I need to know is where to put the 2nd AJAX call that updates the HTML table? Pseudo code will be fine or a link to an example would also be helpful.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are two different transactions, dependent on each other in any way, or both are completely independent. I hope they are independent, then instead on sending on batch request for all the transactions, can we send each request Async and get the result. Now based on that result you can update the html ...

Comment: Yes, two seperate, not dependent. Both async.

Comment: I've tried doing it that way but it does not work. The for loop which processes the transactions completes before any rows are updated and only turns the last row in the table red or green.

Comment: Can you please show the code, which you had tried ...

Comment: As stated in the post this code does not work and only updates the last row. I have hard coded in 4 so the loop didn't process all the records while testing. This code only updated the last row in the table unless I uncommected the alert() which forced the code to stop until the response was received.

Comment: Try creating httpObject inside the loop ... Instead of one global httpObject, have httpObject for each request ....

Comment: Thanks for trying Nitin but that was not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not practical to do what you are suggesting by continuously hitting the server to check for 'completion'.

> I am using ajax to call a .php page
>   which in turn queries the database for
>   all the transactions, and then in a
>   loop processes the transactions
>   through the merchant and updates the
>   database with either a success or
>   fail.

This loop should also update the tables with a success or fail, if you post the code where you are having a problem, I'd be glad to extend this answer and help solve it.

Comment: I've added the code to the post. As stated in the post this code does not work and only updates the last row. I have hard coded in 4 so the loop didn't process all the records while testing. This code only updated the last row in the table unless I uncommected the alert() which forced the code to stop until the response was received. The for loop will be an array of order id's created while the html table is created.

Comment: Greg, that was my first thought as it was quite obvious to update each record after the response was returned however trying to update each record did not work. The loop processes all the AJAX calls before a response is returned. Only the last record is actually updated in the HTML table. If you have an answer to my original question I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The ajax calls can have a callback assigned to them using 'onload' event. Give your ajax iframe a function to update its desired row